# AngularJS component: $doCheck won't run for fake HTTP request with $q.when()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components, angularjs-digest

I created [Simple Angular textarea component with characters counter, made with $doCheck component hook on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RiQD8a?p=preview), which counts characters on [$doCheck](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2016/07/component-lifecycle-docheck-angular-15x_22.html) hook. I read that [it should run for every digest cycle](http://www.codelord.net/2016/12/20/replacing-angulars-deep-watches-with-the-%24docheck-lifecycle-hook/), so it should work:

```
$ctrl.load = function () {
    HTTPService
      .get()
      .then(_bindElement);
  }
function _bindElement (element) {
    $ctrl.element = element;
  }
```

Cause at least digets runs - value changes inside component, it is also displayed on parent's `<p>`. But counter does not change, am I missing something, this is not true that `$doCheck` runs on every digest cycle? I use `$q.when()` for simulation of HTTP request - I also tried `$timeout` to force digest, but it didn't work. Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: It's not clear how the behaviour differs from real http request. From what I see [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpqVI0ktk5fMAo7gMjk1?p=preview), it's absolutely same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I have to manually call `digest` with `timeout` when character count changes, cause it looks like assignments inside `$doCheck` to not trigger `digest`, and that's why view was out of sync with model. Working plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/M6I5sB?p=info.